# best practice for extending dynamic templates?

Tags: django-templates

I need to render nested templates and as obvious these templates have many to many relation (eg. forum calls news, menus, videos etc.. and vice versa).

Im new to DJango and the only solution I can think abt is repetitive calls between them.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ExtendingTemplates) may prove to be helpful. It has got some documentation on extending django templates. Also see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#template-inheritance) for some info on the template inheritance mechanism. If you want to extend the **template engine**, then see [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter10/).